# In Java, do using "shortcut" variables impact performance?

Tags: java

I have the following piece of code:

```
Player player = (Player)Main.getInstance().getPlayer();
player.setSpeedModifier(keyMap[GLFW_KEY_LEFT_SHIFT] ? 1.8f : 1);
if (keyMap[GLFW_KEY_W]) {
    player.moveForward();
}
if (keyMap[GLFW_KEY_S]) {
    player.moveBackward();
}
player.rotateTowards(getMousePositionInWorld());
```

I was wondering if the usage of a local variable (For the player) to make the code more readable has any impact on performance or whether it would be optimised during compilation to replace the uses of the variable seeing as it is just a straight copy of another variable. Whilst it is possible to keep the long version in place, I prefer the readability of having the shorter version. I understand that the performance impact if there was any would be miniscule, but was just interested if there would be any whatsoever.

Thanks, -Slendy.

Comment: I don't believe it should make a difference in performance.  A decent compiler will optimize either form to use a register if it can, and only write back the final value to a global if needed.  Ditto with a local variable.  The rule here is not NEVER optimize code until you've measured its performance and you KNOW you need to make it faster.

Comment: I am curious if the compiler would be able to reliably determine if the return value of `Main.getInstance().getPlayer()` is constant. It may or may not be able to. If not, I would expect the version without the 'shortcut variable' may have a (negligibly) worse execution time due to the function call overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any modern compiler, this will most likely be optimized away and it will not have any performance implications. The few additional bytes used for storage are well worth the added readability.

Answer (score 3):

consider these 2 pieces of code:

```
final Player player = (Player)Main.getInstance().getPlayer();
player.callmethod1();
player.callmethod2();
```

and:

```
((Player)Main.getInstance().getPlayer()).callmethod1();
((Player)Main.getInstance().getPlayer()).callmethod2();
```

There are reasons, why first variant is preferable:

1. First one is more readable, at least because of line length
2. Java compiler cannot assume that the same object will be returned by `Main.getInstance().getPlayer()` this is why second variant will actually call `getPlayer` twice, which could be performance penalty

Comment: ad 2: The JIT might recognize and optimize that, but you point 1 remains valid, so really the firsti alternative is to be preferred.

Comment: @glglgl true, JIT might recognize it during runtime, might not, depends on so many factors, including moon-phase, so I prefer not to rely on that

Comment: Completely right. I always moan at my colleague who leaves me with stuff like `frobnicate(Controller.getInstance().getFoo().getBar().getBaz1(), Controller.getInstance().getFoo().getBar().getBaz2(), Controller.getInstance().getFoo().getBar().getBaz3());` instead of a very well readable `Bar bar = Controller.getInstance().getFoo().getBar(); frobnicate(bar.getBaz1(), bar.getBaz2(), bar.getBaz3());`. It is nice to read and can be understood at one glance...

Comment: In 2), if the variable returned by getPlayer() (If its return value is even tied to a member variable! It could return random garbage for all we know) is not final (and possibly other modifiers and conditions of which I am ignorant), the JIT can not know that no other thread has changed its return value.

Comment: The Player variable stored in the instance is essentially only set when the player chooses to take a course of action that would alter it, it isn't set at any pre-determined point. If the player chooses to load a game, it is overwritten, just as it is when they start a new game.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the probably unneeded `(Player)` cast, I even find your version to be superior to having long worms of calls.

IMHO if you need one special object more than once or twice, it is worth to be saved in a local variable.

The local variable will need some bytes on the stack, but on the other hand, several calls are omitted, so your version clearly wins.

Comment: The player cast is used because my code is in two packages. One has a template (BasePlayer) and the other has an implementation (Player). My instance setup stores a BasePlayer from which I can implement extra functionality, but the cast is necessary in order to utilise implementation-specific functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest performance hit will likely be the function lookup of the objects:

```
(Player)Main.getInstance().getPlayer();
```

Otherwise, you want to minimize these function calls if possible.  In this case, a local var could save CPU, though if you have a global var, it might be a hair faster to use it.

It really depends on how many times this is done in a loop though.  Quite likely you will see no difference either way in normal usage. :)